# How to modify variables from another file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently working with the `discord.js` library.
I guess I can call it by this name, but whenever I want to access a file, this doesn't work.

Let's say I have a file called `calc.js` and I want to access the `main.js` file and take a variable out of there using exports and require it to just take the value out of it.

But I haven't found even one way online to modify the variables and return another value to the file.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Javascript pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 2):

As noted, JavaScript doesn't pass every variable by reference. If you need to access a primitive value like a number, you could declare it as a local variable and export functions to access and modify it. Something like this rough example:

### increment.js

```
let count = 0;

module.exports = {
  get:       () => count,
  increment: () => ++count
};
```

### main.js

```
const { get, increment } = require('./increment.js');

console.log(get());
console.log(increment());
console.log(get());
```

**Edit:** You should probably not name your accessor `get`, as that's the key word used to describe [getters in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). Or better yet, turn such a `get` function into a getter with a more suitable name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary/map:

#### variables.js

```
let variables = {};

export { variables };
```

#### main.js

```
const { variables } = require('./variables.js');

variables.x = 'whatever';
```